# Customize-cra config-overrides.js is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, customize-cra

I am working on the create-react-app project with typescript. I am trying to use _ (lodash) globally. I followed manuals step by step trying to figure out how to do it, but without any success.
I followed this tutorial https://www.npmjs.com/package/customize-cra. My package.json contains between **dependecies**:

```
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",

"react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",

"save-dev": "^0.0.1-security"
```

In **devDependencies**:

```
"customize-cra": "^1.0.0"
```

Based on tutorials I changed also **scripts**:

```
 "scripts": {
"start": "react-app-rewired start",
"build": "react-app-rewired build",
"test": "react-app-rewired test",...
```

My **config-overrides.js** is located in root folder:

```
const { addDecoratorsLegacy, override, disableEsLint } = require('customize-cra')
const webpack = require('webpack')

function myOverrides(config) {
  if (!config.plugins) {
    config.plugins = []
  }
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      _: 'lodash',
    }),
  )
  return config
}

module.exports = override(
  addDecoratorsLegacy(),
  disableEsLint(),
  myOverrides
)
```

I try to use `join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ')` but failed with error.

```
TypeScript error in C:/Users/.../webapp/src/index.tsx(27,1): Cannot find name 'join'.  TS2304
```

Does anybody have any idea what should go wrong?
Thank you.